# Which database will feature stapling affect?

Tags: wss-3.0, database, feature-stapling

We are testing feature stapling and need to revert to a point before the feature stapling was run.

To do this do we just need to restore the content database, or do we also need to restore the configuration database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is your feature doing? Depending on the modifications it makes in code it could touch either config and /or content databases.

Comment: Thanks, we found the bug in the script so now no need to restore :)

Comment: Out of curiosity (and thinking of future searchers), what changes would alter which database?